# Watch Dogs plot hole: Keeping your identity secret

Tags: watch-dogs

This is either a gaping plot hole staring me right in the face or I must have missed something.

Alright, so you take certain measures to make sure your identity as the vigilante is kept secret, for instance scrambling all ctOS camera feeds to blur your face rendering it unable to identify you, even going to extreme lengths in the instance of that one prison mission to make sure the witness from the stadium does not talk. All understandable, to make sure no one figures out who you are & ends up going after your family, all to keep them safe. Fine. BUT.

At one point while I'm driving around a message comes on the radio where the announcer says something along the lines of "***Police are still looking for vigilante Aiden Pearce, but with the Chicago public supporting Pearce police are having a hard time figuring out his whereabouts***". And it wasn't like a major news headline "**We discovered who the vigilante is!**" or anything of the sort, the announcer just casually states the vigilante's identity. So what boggles my mind is..if it's public knowledge.. why am I doing all this to keep my identity secret?! If who I am is already public knowledge, why hasn't the police gone for my family or something?

Not to mention when you're walking in the street & you'll come across the occasional bystander that'll be like "***Hey! That's the guy from the news!***" or "***Hey, that's the vigilante!***", & pull out their phone to take a picture of me with Aiden taking NO reaction whatsoever to delete the photo or block their camera or anything. He just casually strolls on. How the hell is that bystander able to identify me?! Don't I have my mask thing up everytime I'm on the news? And why doesn't Aiden do anything about it?!

Someone please, is this a massive plot hole or am I missing something??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you're right this is a huge plot hole. His own sister doesn't even realize it right away

Answer (score 0):

The mission that makes you go into the prison to shut the stadium witness up gives the police your identity, The new reports outcasted that 'Joe Smith (or smth) was mistakenly identified' blah blah blah  and all those lots they know Pearce's name but do not know what he looks like as he hacks into the ctOS to stop identification system on cameras to recognize that mysterious face of his.